# How to show data for each week in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have a problem in displaying the data in my application for each week?

I can show the data by day using this code in my SQLite

```
SELECT substr(_id, 1, 7) as _id, sum(value) as total FROM pd_table GROUP BY _id order by _id desc
```

[image: This is the output after I execute the code above]

I was also able to display the data based on the month by using this code

```
SELECT substr(_id, 1, 10) as _id, sum(value) as total FROM pd_table GROUP BY _id order by _id desc
```

[image: This is the output after I execute the code above]

_id using SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss")

now i want to display it every week. How?

Any answer is very useful for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has internal date/time formatting function strftime, and one of possible format option is a week number. So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%W',_id) as week_of_year, sum(value) as total 
       FROM pd_table 
       GROUP BY week_of_year order by _id desc
```

Though I didn't try it on Android. See more here: http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: alhamdulillah it's work. But I did not use WEEK_OF_YEAR because it does not work in my listview and replacing it with _id. thanks a lot :)